# How to compute average every 5 seconds based on time column in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a dataset like below, Its time col is based on milliseconds.

```
pid_col ,timestamp_col ,value_col
31,2019-03-29 07:14:56.999999756,0.0
31,2019-03-29 07:14:57.250000,0.614595
31,2019-03-29 07:14:57.500000,0.678615
31,2019-03-29 07:14:57.750000,0.687578
31,2019-03-29 07:14:58.000000244,0.559804
31,2019-03-29 07:14:58.250000,0.522672
31,2019-03-29 07:14:58.499999512,0.51627
31,2019-03-29 07:14:58.750000,0.51627
31,2019-03-29 07:14:59.000000244,0.517551
31,2019-03-29 07:14:59.250000,0.51627
31,2019-03-29 07:14:59.500000244,0.509868
31,2019-03-29 07:14:59.750000488,0.513709
31,2019-03-29 07:15:00,0.513709
31,2019-03-29 07:15:00.249999512,0.518831
31,2019-03-29 07:15:00.500000,0.531635
```

How could I compute the average of values in every 5 seconds??
I've used resample but it didn't work. here is my code:

```
col_list = ["timestamp", "pid","value"]
df = read_csv("data.csv", usecols=col_list)
df['timestamp'] = to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
timestamp_col=df['timestamp'].tolist()
pid_col=df['pid'].tolist()
value_col=df['value'].tolist()

df['timestamp'].resample('5S').mean()
timestamp_col=df['timestamp'].tolist()
```

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `timestamp_col` as index before resample:

```
>>> df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('pid') \
      .resample('5S')['value'].mean().reset_index()

   pid           timestamp     value
0   31 2019-03-29 07:14:55  0.512767
1   31 2019-03-29 07:15:00  0.521392
```

**Update**

Maybe you prefer this version:

```
>>> df.groupby(['pid', pd.Grouper(freq='5S', key='timestamp')], as_index=False) \
      .agg({'pid': 'first', 'timestamp': 'first', 'value': 'mean'})

   pid                     timestamp     value
0   31 2019-03-29 07:14:56.999999756  0.512767
1   31 2019-03-29 07:15:00.000000000  0.521392
```

Comment: Is it what you expect and does it solve your problem?

Comment: yes thanks a lot, but time has started at 07:14:56 ! why the code compute from 7:14:55?whats the value at this time!?

Comment: The resample takes an interval of every 5 seconds from [07:14:55-07:15:00) and [07:15:00-07:15:05). The label of this interval is left (by default). It doesn't care of the first label of the interval. Check my updated answer, please.

Comment: sorry I get confused! would you please help me?? for this dataset I should exactly compute the avg of values every five seconds... I mean values for the first 5 seconds should compute between 7:14:56 till 7:15:01 and so on for every 5 seconds.